# Intercept annotated classes and methods in Spring AOP or AspectJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

So I have a custom annotation

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Intercepted {}
```

that I want to use to weave aspects into methods (AspectJ, `@annotation(Intercepted)`).

The idea is that I weave the aspect in when I annotate the method `@Intercepted` directly -- that part works -- or if I annotate the class, the aspect should be weaved into all its (public) methods -- that part doesn't.

Furthermore, if I annotate a class *and* one of its methods, the aspect should only get weaved in once, the method-level annotation overriding the class-level one.

Essentially, I want an "add the class-level annotation if there's a class-level annotation, but only if there isn't already a method-level annotation."

How do I do that?

Comment: I think that is **not** a property of any annotation, it is the annotation **framework** that does this. With JAX-RS for example, when you apply a filter annotation to a class, all endpoints within the class are automatically going through that filter, too.

Comment: @GhostCat Oh. So I'll have to look to AspectJ to find a way to define my interceptor, rather than tweak my annotation implementation? Thank you!

Comment: I very much think so. Keep in mind: annotations are just that: "notes attached to a class or method". The annotation itself doesn't contain **any** implementation. It is *other* code that acts on the presence of that annotation!

Comment: I improved your question title. What you are talking about is unrelated to "annotation inheritance from class to method", whatever you imagine that might be. You just want to intercept annotated classes and methods, no matter on which of the two the annotation is found. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an AspectJ example. The pointcut syntax is the same in Spring AOP.

**Helper classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Intercepted {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

@Intercepted
public class AnnotatedClass {
  public void doSomething() {}
  public void doSomethingElse() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class AnnotatedMethod {
  @Intercepted
  public void doSomething() {}
  public void doSomethingElse() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

@Intercepted
public class AnnotatedMixed {
  @Intercepted
  public void doSomething() {}
  public void doSomethingElse() {}
}
```

**Driver application (Java SE, no Spring):**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Should be logged
    new AnnotatedClass().doSomething();
    // Should be logged
    new AnnotatedClass().doSomethingElse();

    // Should be logged
    new AnnotatedMethod().doSomething();
    // Should NOT be logged
    new AnnotatedMethod().doSomethingElse();

    // Should be logged, but only once
    new AnnotatedMixed().doSomething();
    // Should be logged
    new AnnotatedMixed().doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

Please note that the `execution(* *(..)) &&` part is not necessary in Spring AOP because only method execution joinpoints are supported there. The pointcut could just be `annotatedMethod() || annotatedClass()` there. In AspectJ I have to be more precise because otherwise other joinpoint types would be logged.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class AnnotationInterceptor {
  @Pointcut("@annotation(de.scrum_master.app.Intercepted)")
  public void annotatedMethod() {}

  @Pointcut("@within(de.scrum_master.app.Intercepted)")
  public void annotatedClass() {}

  @Before("execution(* *(..)) && (annotatedMethod() || annotatedClass())")
  public void log(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.AnnotatedClass.doSomething())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.AnnotatedClass.doSomethingElse())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.AnnotatedMethod.doSomething())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.AnnotatedMixed.doSomething())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.AnnotatedMixed.doSomethingElse())
```